# How do I make gif animation match fullscreen window size in Python using Pyglet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyglet

So, couple hours ago I found Pyglet best for me for rendering gif animations, so I', new in this. My problem is that the animated gif renders at its original size in fullscreen window, I need to make it match, but I can't figure out how I should do this, any help? My code:

```
import sys

import pyglet
from pyglet.window import Platform

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    animation = pyglet.image.load_animation(sys.argv[1])
    bin = pyglet.image.atlas.TextureBin()
    animation.add_to_texture_bin(bin)
else:
    animation = pyglet.resource.animation('gaben.gif')
    sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

screen = Platform().get_default_display().get_default_screen()
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=screen.width, height=screen.height)
window.set_fullscreen(True)

pyglet.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

The result what I get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the sprite object's `.scale`.
It has the ability to scale the image in proportion to it's original dimensions and you don't need to worry about mapping data or filling in pixel-gaps if you resize the image yourself some how.

To help you get going, this is a simple example of a implementation:
(And it looks like this: https://youtu.be/Ly61VvTZnCU)

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import Platform

monitor = Platform().get_default_display().get_default_screen()

sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.resource.animation('anim.gif'))

H_ratio = max(sprite.height, monitor.height) / min(sprite.height, monitor.height)
W_ratio = max(sprite.width, monitor.width) / min(sprite.width, monitor.width)

sprite.scale = min(H_ratio, W_ratio) # sprite.scale = 2 would double the size.
                                     # We'll upscale to the lowest of width/height
                                     # to not go out of bounds. Whichever
                                     # value hits the screen edges first essentially.

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=monitor.width, height=monitor.height, fullscreen=True)

pyglet.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

I removed some of your code for demo/testing purposes.
The code is by no means perfect, but it will hopefully give you an insight as to how this works).